# Plugging in webcam microphone causes sound to stop working

Tags: audio, camera, microphone

Back when COVID started, I got myself a USB webcam ([this one, to be specific](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B086WVNS2G)). I found the fact that you have to plug it into the audio jack to be a little annoying, but otherwise it worked fine. For reference, I was running Windows 10 back then.

Recently I switched to Linux Mint (Ulyana Cinnamon, if it's any help). When I try to use my webcam the video works, but my computer's audio stops working for the duration of having the webcam plugged in. I *think* the computer is getting the microphone input mixed up with sound output, <strike>but I'm not sure.</strike> **CONFIRMED: When I checked in Pulse Audio Volume Control, the microphone input matched the sound output.** My computer has no other microphones or webcams (it's a desktop), so I would appreciate it if y'all could help me resolve this quickly.

EDIT: You might want to zoom your browser out before viewing the pictures, they are a bit large.

**Debug output from terminal:**

```
$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3234 Analog [ALC3234 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC3234 Alt Analog [ALC3234 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ lspci | grep Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio

$ journalctl -f
-- Logs begin at Mon 2020-07-27 12:10:35 CDT. --
Aug 01 12:22:24 user-OptiPlex-7050 rtkit-daemon[980]: Supervising 4 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Aug 01 12:22:34 user-OptiPlex-7050 dbus-daemon[1229]: [session uid=1000 pid=1229] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.134' (uid=1000 pid=11104 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real " label="unconfined")
Aug 01 12:22:34 user-OptiPlex-7050 systemd[1213]: Created slice apps.slice.
Aug 01 12:22:34 user-OptiPlex-7050 systemd[1213]: Created slice apps-org.gnome.Terminal.slice.
Aug 01 12:22:34 user-OptiPlex-7050 systemd[1213]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Aug 01 12:22:34 user-OptiPlex-7050 dbus-daemon[1229]: [session uid=1000 pid=1229] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
Aug 01 12:22:34 user-OptiPlex-7050 systemd[1213]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Aug 01 12:22:34 user-OptiPlex-7050 systemd[1213]: Started VTE child process 11115 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 11107.
Aug 01 12:22:35 user-OptiPlex-7050 pk-debconf-help[7706]: No active connections, exiting
Aug 01 12:22:35 user-OptiPlex-7050 systemd[1213]: pk-debconf-helper.service: Succeeded.

Aug 01 12:23:19 user-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s31f6 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:cc:2d:21:f0:0c:00:08:00 SRC=192.168.39.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=13838 PROTO=2 
Aug 01 12:23:24 user-OptiPlex-7050 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s31f6 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:14:0a:c5:46:da:09:08:00 SRC=192.168.39.191 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2
```

**Sound/Output in settings without microphone plugged in:**

[image: Sound/Output without microphone plugged in]

**Sound/Output with microphone plugged in:**

[image: Sound/Output with microphone plugged in]

**Sound/Input without microphone plugged in:**

[image: Sound/Input without microphone plugged in]

**Sound/Input with microphone plugged in (1):**

[image]

**Sound/Input with microphone plugged in (2):**

[image]

Pulse Audio Video Control (PAVC) Output Devices tab without microphone:

[image]

PAVC Output Devices with microphone:

[image]

PAVC Input Devices without microphone:

[image]

PAVC Input Devices with microphone:

[image]

PAVC Configuration (doesn't change if mic is plugged in or not):

[image]

Sound / Applications:

[image]

Comment: So your webcam has a usb plug and a microphone with its own 3.5mm jack that plugs into your microphone port on your sound card? Is that right? Is the jack TRRS?

Comment: The microphone plugs into the same jack that my headphones do. I am not familiar with things like "sound card" and "TRRS"; I'm just a random schmuck who dislikes Microsoft's aggressive data gathering.

Comment: I don't have an immediate solution based on the images but just for kicks you might want to try https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/pavucontrol as it gives more options to look around through.

Comment: All devices disappearing might indicate that your camera's driver is wrestling pulseaudio over audio control. How did you install the driver and how old is your camera? If possible, can you run `journalctl -f` before you plug in the camera and include the output here?

Comment: What appears under the "Applications" tab of the sound settings? It sounds like the audio from the applications you're using is being sent to the webcam, which is being treated as "Headphones" for some reason. Different applications can have their audio sent to different devices ("sinks"). PulseAudio might assume that when you start using the webcam, you want to start using all associated audio interfaces.

Comment: @sjy I'm adding a screenshot, along with some screenshots from PuseAudio Volume Control

Comment: Dumb question...  the screen you've labled *"Sound/Output with microphone"*.  What happens when you click the "line out-built in audio" icon.  Likewise the screen you've labled "Pulse Audio Video Control (PAVC) Output" chose the other option in "port" drop down?

Comment: I just suspect this cheap webcam uses a USB headset chip or similar and they haven'd bothered to disable the line out on it, just not wired it into anything.

Comment: @TendersMcChiken I didn't install any drivers, it plugged-and-played. The camera is about 3 months old.

Comment: @PhilipCouling It's the same as when the microphone isn't plugged in.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I tend to agree; the PAVU input tab is only showing the "Monitor of Built-In Analog Stereo", and that only when I allow it to show monitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as it turns out, it is the webcam's fault. The sound chip thingy (?) in the webcam isn't configured properly, such that the computer thinks it's both an input and an output.

**Solution:** In Pulse Audio Volume Control go to the "Configuration" tab and set the audio profile to "Analog Stereo Duplex". Then go to the output tab and set the port to match your speakers (they may or may not be listed as "unavailable"; the computer is lying.) Then, go to the input tab and ensure that the port is set to "Microphone," not "Headset Microphone."